# Why random encounters are harder when playing Baldur's Gate Tutu?

Tags: baldurs-gate, baldurs-gate-tutu

It's so benefical the fact that you can unite almost the entire saga in one game: (BG1 + TotSC) + (BG2:SoA + ToB) with the use of EasyTutu and G3 Widescreen mods.

Now, I don't remember the battles of the very beginning of the game being so.. challenging, in an unjustified way. Once I'm outside, almost everything is hard to beat, One wolf is able to kill Imoen in one bite, she has 8/8 hp.

However I remember that my brother back then used a mod that makes battles even more harder to handle, but all I installed is EasyTutu and the widescreen mod..

Does EasyTutu also make things harder? Is there a way to fix or restore the difficult of the encounters back to the original?

Comment: What difficulty are you playing the game on?

Comment: Also was it a normal wolf or a direwolf?

Comment: Just normal difficulty. Normal wolf.

Comment: Are you able to play only the first game, without tutu?
It was a first install, or you modded tutu over the old one?

Comment: Honestly, this sounds exactly like vanilla Baldur's Gate to me. You are extremely fragile.

Comment: There's a radical difficulty difference between Baldur's Gate Tutu and Baldur's Gate Trilogy. In Tutu you get like 8 Diseased Gibberlings. Whereas Baldur's Gate Trilogy you get 2 or 3. I switched to BG:EE and it's definitively better in almost every aspect (except voices lol).

Answer (score 2):

#### Toughness of an enemy

As far as I can tell, there is no difference between them.

I searched for the changelog, and the features in their webpage and there is no evidence of that.

> [Features](http://usoutpost31.com/easytutu/)
>
> [Changelog](http://usoutpost31.com/easytutu/etfaq.html)

They only put everything under BG2 engine and add few tweaks(ie. as lockpick in BG1 do not give EXP, they had to set it to work properly).

Those good old games usually are very difficult to play, and this game in special, at the beginning it is kind of hard, because you have almost none equipment, and your team stats are almost the same as the enemy (sometimes lower). Making the winner of the fight the ones that attack first.

If you try to play the Baldur's Gate 1 as it is, without the mods, and feel it is easier, it must be because there is a mod someone set on your EasyTutu making it harder.

Yet, you can use some mods to eases it a bit.
http://www.gibberlings3.net/bg2tweaks/index.php
http://www.gibberlings3.net/bg1tweaks/

#### Enemies numbers

This one may hurt your gameplay when low level, the randomness of the encounter may set more enemies than what you are used and are supposed to fight at early stages.

Look for **EasyTutu Spawn Randomizer** in the Easytutu feature site. It's an addon which will help you to not get beaten by six wyverns early on.

#### About the Wolves

```
Wolf(on BG2)                                                                      NWOLF
HP:    24/24      XP: 65

Armor Class                              Resistances
Base     7                               Fire            0%  Cold    0%
Crushing 0     Missile  0                Electricity     0%  Acid    0%
Piercing 0     Slashing 0                Magic           0%
                                         Magical fire    0%  Magical cold    0%
THAC0: 18                                Slashing        0%  Piercing        0%
Number of Attacks: 1                     Crushing        0%  Missile         0%

Abilities           Morale               Saving Throws
Str  18/00 Int  16  Morale          10   Death     13  Breath    16
Dex  9     Wis  9   Breaking Point  5    Wands     15  Spells    16
Con  9     Cha  9   Recovery Time   60   Polymorph 14
Lore 0     Luck 0

Thief Skills                              Fatigue      0
Hide In Shadows    0%  Stealth        0%  Intoxication 0
Set Traps          0%  Disarm Traps   0%
Pick Locks         0%  Pick Pockets   0%
Detect Illusions   0%
```

> [Gamefaqs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/258273-baldurs-gate-ii-shadows-of-amn/faqs/27144)

The str 18/00 changes for each kind of wolf, I found with 18/ 0, 18/40 and 15

I found some math:

With THAC0 18 it should hit against Imoen's 6AC about (12/20) 60% of the time.

STR - Damage / THAC0 Bonus for Playable Characters

```
15 str = no bonuses
16 str = +1 to damage
17 str = + 1 thac0 and damage
18 str = +1 thac0, +2 to damage
18/01-50 = +1 thac0, +3 to damage
18/51-75 = +2 thac0, +3 to damage
18/76-90 = +2 thac0, +4 to damage
18/91-99 = +2 thac0, +5 to damage
18/00 = +3 thac0, +6 to damage
```

I did not found the in game damage stats
But I found the Wolves(The first ones, as the stats above) come equiped with 3 kind weapons(?!?!?).

```
Name   Resource
Attack p1-4
Attack p1-6
Attack p1-10
```

*the bears have B1-8

As the Monster compendium(1989 ver.2) show 2-5 (1d4+1) damage for the fist Wolf, and other sources as (1d6+1) - I don't know which one was used for the Baldur's Gate - I think that the p1-4 could be the dice rolled to damage calculation.

Depending on the spawned Wolf you could be one hit easily without crit, and if the strength damage bonus count for creatures you can get * near death * with de p1-4 hit too.

Comment: The only thing I could think of is that the spawn generator is set too high, so for a 2 person party, coming across a group of wolves at level 1 is going to (probably) kill you BUT OP said that a single wolf one shotted Imoen which makes me think it may be something else

Comment: Last weekend I installed the Baldur's Gate:EE and fought some wolves with Imoen on the first map(after ambush) without equip her, actually I saved, let she be beaten and reload. She always die with 2 hit, never menages to get less, or more(unless some rare cases when the wolf miss). As the average damage I took was 4, if the wolf crit his roll he can one shot her(but this must be as rare as the wolf miss).
That's why I told OP that the game IS hard, and to check if he can play it without the TuTu to check for unwanted mods.

Comment: My bad, I found some math, and the hit is suppose to happen about 60% of the time. So is more rare to get a crit (to roll 20)